# UWP Layout panel for X and Y elements

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, gridview, uwp

I have a Dashboard application app, which uses datatemplates on a given coordinate for the X and Y axes.

[image]

Up until now we have used Datagrid with code-behind to generate DataGridTemplateColumn with a datatemplate. The datagrid is bound to Instances of custom class, with a property for each column (Strongly typed to 50 properties pr now)

Due to horrible scrolling performance (25 columns, 100 rows, and grouping), and due to the fact that UWP Datagrid is unfinished and throws different COMexceptions when adding or removing items trough a grouped CollectionViewSource we have tried the following:

ListView with an string loaded template with a Grid/Grid.Column setup for each cell. But, the ListView does not have selection of cell, which are one requirement from the business.

Therefor we tried the GridView control, with a different source collection. Here we are using MaximumRowsOrColumns equal to the number of columns, and also we are setting the width of the ItemsWrapGrid to equal the width of the number of columns. Then we just fill a collection with all the Instances of classes corresponding to the datatemplate.

Bot the ListView and GridView use a separate ListView to show the column headers, and row headers as displayed. And it seems also difficult to create a good user experience with scrolling and linking of the scrolling between the 3 controls. We use ChangeView to update the other scrollviewer, but there are some kind of lag so the UI experience is not great for this area.

But both of these feel wrong.

The GridView is the closest to our needs, but with this Scenario we have to match the number objects in the collection, so that it appear to follow the correct X and Y coordinate of the grid. So this, as is the ListView option, is working like a hack of the default controls.

We need virtualization, and we would prefer to use standard Windows UI controls with Transitions and everything.

Is there a magic control to properly display objects dynamically in a X,Y coordinate fashion, which also have some sort of selection, virtualization, supports grouping and also have fewer bugs than the existing UWP Datagrid?

Comment: Each control is suitable for different scenarios, and they have different advantages. Currently, uwp provides datagrid, listview, gridview these view controls to display large data sets. Listview displays data in a single column, as you mentioned, you cannot select a 'cell'. The GridView displays a collection of items that can be scrolled vertically. The data is stacked horizontally until the columns are filled, and then continues to the next row. GridView is suitable for items that focus on images.

Comment: For your requirement, it is recommended to use DataGrid. In addition, could you please describe the issue about **UWP Datagrid is unfinished and throws different COMexceptions** detaily? Please make sure CollectionViewSource is successfully bound, you need to use ObservableCollection<T> to GroupedItems and check if the model class has implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have created an bug report on the COMexception in the Github project for datagrid.
https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3924

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. When you delete the last item, you could use clear() method instead to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, and you also can create a new collection, and set the Itemssource again, as we do today. 

And since our dashboard is so rich with controls, this takes 10 seconds on the UI thread for the Datagrid to render. 
And this is after hours upon hours of optimizing the XAML code with {x:Bind} and also x:Load on some of the visuals. 

We have also tried using x:Phase, with some success, but this also bugs out randomly and freezes all the controls.

Comment: This issue has been transferred to GitHub, please follow your progress on GitHub for effective help.